# how to center and elements content while have a background 100%

Tags: html, css

I am trying to setup a layout where the content (can be text or anything), is in the middle while the background color or image is in the entire width. My solution was to create an element-container with the background and a child element with smaller width and `margin: 0 auto;`

(http://jsfiddle.net/kp4D8/1/).

Has anyone else come up with another workaround for a situation like that thats simpler?

Thanks,
Gasim

Comment: You solution looks even simpler and it's the correct way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is how you go about doing this and is probably the best way.

One alternative method you could use though if you wanted to use minimal markup was to cut out the `<section>` element and just apply the `margin` to elements under `.element-container` like this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duSBp/)

```
.element-container * {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.element-container h2 {
    text-align: right;
}
```

The reason I would prefer to go with your original method is so I can style the background of the inner element more easily and style everything together without the use of the `*` selector.

Comment: I actually like this idea a lot. But i would only apply it to the direct children: `element-container > *`.